# Current Date minus one with a date defined as a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a SQL `where` clause like this:

```
AND (((@Shift = 1 
       AND QtyHistoryDetails.stgtxndate 
              BETWEEN (CONVERT(CHAR(10), @StartDate, 101)) + ' 6:00:00' 
                  AND (CONVERT(CHAR(10), @StartDate, 101)) + ' 14:30:00')
     OR (@Shift = 2 
         AND QtyHistoryDetails.stgtxndate 
                BETWEEN (CONVERT(CHAR(10), @StartDate, 101)) + ' 14:00:00' 
                    AND (CONVERT(CHAR(10), @StartDate, 101)) + ' 22:30:00')
     OR (@Shift = 3 
         AND QtyHistoryDetails.stgtxndate 
                BETWEEN (CONVERT(CHAR(10), @StartDate, 101)) + ' 23:00:00' 
                    AND (CONVERT(CHAR(10), @StartDate, 101)) + ' 6:30:00')))
AND cpdPressResource IS NOT NULL
AND cpdmold IS NOT NULL
AND cpdCavities IS NOT NULL
```

I am focused on `SHIFT = 3`: I need a way to have the data pulled from `@shift3` and minus 1 day to show data from the previous day up to select date. Is this possible?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: @jarlh This is in SQL

Comment: It's certainly not ANSI/ISO SQL. E.g. convert() is a product specific function.

Comment: @Jarlh, so to give context, I need to pass a string value that equal to a date. SO in my case the string value is @shift=X. User will sub X with a number between 1 and 3.

What I am trying to do is say when you pick 3, you get to see everything from the previous day between "10pm" and "12am" to today 12:00:01am to 6:pm. 

How would I do that?

Comment: I guess you mean Sql *Server*? Then please add that tag

Answer (score 0):

It is not 100% clear what the best way to solve this is.  You have taken part of a query out of context.  And you have provided no sample data or desired results.

I think you can do:

```
 OR (@Shift = 3 AND
     QtyHistoryDetails.stgtxndate >= CONVERT(CHAR(10), @StartDate, 101)) + ' 23:00:00' AND
     QtyHistoryDetails.stgtxndate < CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, 1, @StartDate), 101)) + ' 6:30:00'
    )
```

To be honest, SQL Server allows you to add two `datetime` values together.  So, if `@StartDate` is declared as a `datetime`, you can use:

```
 OR (@Shift = 3 AND
     QtyHistoryDetails.stgtxndate >= @StartDate + ' 23:00:00' AND
     QtyHistoryDetails.stgtxndate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @StartDate) + ' 6:30:00'
    )
```